# How can I add text and images to dates within the React Day Picker library, specifically in version 8?

Tags: reactjs, version, libraries, react-day-picker

I get errors when attempting to utilize the renderDay prop within the DayPicker component.
Previously, the functionality operated smoothly in version 7; however, it is now displaying the aforementioned error.

```
 <DayPicker
      onDayClick={handleDayClick}
      modifiers={activeModifiers} // Pass the modifier functions to the modifiers prop
      numberOfMonths={1}
      selected={selectedRange}
      onDayClick={handleDayClick}
      renderDay={(day) => {
          console.log(day, "daydaydayday");
          const price = prices[day];
          return (
            <div>
              hello
              {day.toLocaleDateString()}
              {price && <span> - ${price}</span>}
            </div>
          );
        }}
    />
```